# Animate button when corresponding action is executed thru hotkey

Tags: java, swing, animation, action, key-bindings

I have actions coupled with buttons as well as hotkeys. I want to animate(animation similar to the one exhibited during mouse click) the button when its respective action is triggered thru hotkeys. Is that possible?

I am doing as follows:

```
        btnAdd.setAction(addDataAction);
        panelAdd.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT)
                .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl ENTER"), addDataAction);
        panelAdd.getActionMap().put(addDataAction, addDataAction);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does the trick for me (not elegant but it works)

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        final JButton button = new JButton();
        AbstractAction action = new AbstractAction("Hello World!") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                button.getModel().setArmed(true);
                button.getModel().setPressed(true);
                Timer t = new Timer(200, new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        button.getModel().setArmed(false);
                        button.getModel().setPressed(false);
                    }
                });
                t.setRepeats(false);
                t.start();
                // Do action stuff
            }
        };
        button.setAction(action);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(button);

        panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl ENTER"), action);
        panel.getActionMap().put(action, action);

        t.add(panel);

        t.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        t.pack();
        t.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

From the [Java API docs for ButtonModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonModel.html):

> Pressing the mouse on top of a button makes the model both armed and pressed. As long as the mouse remains down, the model remains pressed, even if the mouse moves outside the button. On the contrary, the model is only armed while the mouse remains pressed within the bounds of the button (it can move in or out of the button, but the model is only armed during the portion of time spent within the button). A button is triggered, and an ActionEvent is fired, when the mouse is released while the model is armed - meaning when it is released over top of the button after the mouse has previously been pressed on that button (and not already released). Upon mouse release, the model becomes unarmed and unpressed.

Comment: You can also set the pressed state if you override the `processKeyBinding` method of the panel and check for the right key press for the action, then at least your action won't have to be aware of the button.

Comment: It works! but this is different from the actual. If mouse clicked, button gets blue background, which is not happening here. Anyway Nice answer! Thanks.

Comment: To get the "blue" background do `setArmed(true)` then `setPressed(true)` and then in the timer event `setArmed(false)` then `setPressed(false)`. The order is important else your action will be called again.

Comment: I am facing one big issue, that keeping the button pressed for 200ms makes repeated action, which is not supposed to work that way.

Comment: Are you calling `setArmed(false)` before `setPressed(false)`? If `setPressed(false)` is called while the button is armed then your action will be fire again.

Comment: Yes I do. I guess calling `setPressed(true)` fires the action again.

Comment: `setAction(null)` before `setPressed(true)` and setAction(action) after `setPressed(false)` solved the issue.

Comment: When hotkeys are pressed and held, it is triggering actions continuously. How to avoid this. Any suggestions?

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify the button states but i see you found a solution :) To prevent the key repeats you might have to keep a flag for if the hotkeys are down, then set it on keyPressed() and clear it on keyReleased() (there might be a better way).

Answer (score 1):

See [`AbstractButton.setPressedIcon(Icon)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setPressedIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29) (and related methods that accept an `Icon`).  The idea would be to set a non-animated icon as the standard icon, and an animated GIF as the alternate.